# Problems with Infinite Crouton in Android only appears once

Tags: android, crouton

I show the crouton using the following code. At first run of the application the Crouton appears. But if I hit back button and reopen the application from launcher or recent list Crouton doesn't appear.

> public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
> }
>
>
> @Override
> protected void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();
>     Style infinite = new Style.Builder().setBackgroundColorValue(
>             Style.holoBlueLight).build();
>
>     Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder().setDuration(
>             Configuration.DURATION_INFINITE).build();
>
>     Crouton crouton = Crouton.makeText(this, "Hello world", infinite);
>     crouton.setConfiguration(configuration);
>     crouton.show();
> }
> ```
>
> }

Showing the crouton either in the onCreate or in onResume doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work as intended by holding a reference to the displayed crouton and in onPause canceling the crouton.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Crouton mCrouton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Style infinite = new Style.Builder().setBackgroundColorValue(
                Style.holoBlueLight).build();


        Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder().setDuration(
                Configuration.DURATION_INFINITE).build();

        mCrouton = Crouton.makeText(this, "Hello world", infinite);
        mCrouton.setConfiguration(configuration);
        mCrouton.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mCrouton.cancel();
    }
}
```

Also there are other ways using which this issue can be solved.

- `Crouton.clearCroutonsForActivity(this);`
- `Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();`

Use what suits your needs.